# What does it mean when screen flashes blue?

Tags: mirrors-edge

I purchased Mirror's Edge on Steam, unfortunately EA did not include the instruction manual in the Steam version of this game.
Can anyone explain me what does the "blue flashing screen" effect mean? It happens sometimes when I start a level.
Alternately, is there a place where I can get the instruction manual?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The blue flash indicates that your "reaction time" - the slow-motion mode you can activate in melee combat - is recharged. This is mentioned on page 8 of the manual but not, if I recall correctly, anywhere in game.

As for the manual, there are scans available on [ReplacementDocs](http://replacementdocs.com/download.php?view.7366), at least for the PS3 version; as far as I know, there's no official way to get the manual other than buying a hardcopy of the game. (Edit: @lunboks is better at searching than I am and provides a link to [the official PC manual](http://akamai.cdn.ea.com/eadownloads/u/f/manuals/GAME-MIRRORSEDGE/Manuals.zip) in the comments.)

Comment: As god is my witness, I actually own Mirror's Edge on Origin. They give you an [official download of the game manual](http://akamai.cdn.ea.com/eadownloads/u/f/manuals/GAME-MIRRORSEDGE/Manuals.zip). PC version only though.

Comment: @lunboks: Most of us do, after the recent humblebundle that sold it + a bunch of other games on Steam *and* origin for $1.

Comment: @BlueRaja Oh yeah, that's a thing that happened. Not where I got it from though. Not that it matters.

Answer (score 5):

When the screen flashes blue, it means your 'reaction time' is charged, allowing you to turn the level into slow-motion for a few seconds when you press a certain button (square of PlayStation, X for Xbox, and R for PC). Running will also recharge your reaction time They only briefly mention all this in the tutorial.

To get a manual I think the only way is to buy the actual packaged game disk (although they might have it on Steam. To check if it is there, right-click the game, click 'view store page' and then see if there is a 'view the manual' link in the lower right.

Comment: I checked in Steam but could not find a "view the manual" link for this game.

Comment: That's why I said "might". They only have some of the games' manuals.